# Cisco ACLs: Whitelist approach to ACLs

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, acl

I have been looking around and it seems list this would be a simple question so I am sorry if there is a duplicate somewhere.

I have a switch that is carrying a vlan 20 which is holding a /24 .

the network is 10.10.0.1 /24

```
ip access-list extended jimmys_wireless
 deny   ip any 10.11.0.0 0.0.0.255
 deny   ip any 10.12.0.0 0.0.0.255
 deny   ip any 172.16.1.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip any any
```

I have tried doing something like

```
ip access-list extended jimmys_wireless
 permit ip any 10.10.0.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip any 10.10.0.1 0.0.0.255 # default gateway
 deny ip any any
```

I get an ip but cannot get out to the internet at all. this network should only have access to internet and its own network. I want this because if I change the network or add anything, I wound have to update the blacklist to deny it.

Edit I have this set this for in . I think I tried this for in and I couldn't get an IP.

Comment: could you check your NAT/PAT? ISP drops the private IP address, maybe that's why you can not access the internet.

Comment: I think this is unlikely the issue, do you have a better suggestion for the ACLs apart from checking my ISP? I would think if these problems existed, then I would suffer from this regardless of the ACL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ACL you're setting up has to be applied to the VLAN interface as incoming, and should simply look like this:

```
ip access-list extended jimmys_wireless
 /*permits here*/
 deny ip any 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.255
 deny ip any 172.16.0.0 0.15.255.255
 deny ip any 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255
 permit ip any any
```

This way, all local addresses are banned, all public addresses (a.k.a. "The Internet") are allowed. You don't need to allow the gateway IP address, as it is just used to relay traffic for Internet IPs. But, as it won't be the destination IP of any IP packet, it doesn't need to be allowed in your ACL.

Comment: There is nothing allowed (no permit statements) in this ACL. The `deny ip any any` on the last line is gratuitous since it is inherent in any ACL.

Comment: OK. you fixed that problem, but your wildcard masks are incorrect. It is still would not be a whitelist solution, which would be permit statements followed by the deny all.

Comment: Thanks again. I worked too many ASAs in the last time, so I forgot about the wildcard masks so common on Ciscos :-/ And yes, you're also right on the whitelist solution - it would just make no sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at whether it's applied inbound or outbound (you didn't specify), and the source and destination on each line. It's also important on which interface (you didn't specify) you apply the ACL.

You need to think it through and select the correct interface, correct direction, and the correct source and destination for what you want to do.

A better explanation would help us to help you.